# SUM of COUNT(DISTINCT date)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some difficulty with the following SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(mycount) 
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `User`) AS mycount 
     FROM `DBname` 
     WHERE date(Created) >= '2016-07-01'
    ) as R ;
```

The goal is to sum the count of unique entries over the course of the month.

Comment: So you want the distinct count by day, then you want to add all those up? If so, your subquery needs a `GROUP BY date(Created)`. As it stands, your subquery returns one row, the distinct count of users for since July 1.

Comment: Thanks. What's the syntax on that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(mycount) 
FROM  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `User`) AS mycount 
    FROM DBname 
    WHERE date(Created) >= '2016-07-01'
    GROUP BY date(Created)
) as R ;
```